# How can I not click on Multiple Buttons together?

Tags: android, button, onclick, listener

[image]

My application has 3 buttons as shown above. What I want to happen is when one button is pressed then the other two are set as inactive.  How can I accomplish this?

This is my code of **MainActivity.java:**

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button1.setSelected(!button1.isSelected());
    }         
});

button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {        
        button2.setSelected(!button2.isSelected());
    }
});

button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button3.setSelected(!button3.isSelected());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

tr this. this is for button1 you can implement for other two too

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                button1.setSelected(!button1.isSelected());
                button2.setVisibility(Vew.GONE); // this will disappear your buttons
                button3.setVisibility(Vew.GONE);
                button1.setEnable(false); // to disable the button for further clicks 

                }

        });
```

if you only want to disable your buttons then call this setEnable instead of setVisibilty method

Answer (score 1):

Set a variable for each button that will store whether the button was clicked(or then clicked again).
Then, when clicking each button, set that variable to the current state of the button,
and set the other buttons enabled state accordingly.

**Code:**

```
Boolean isButtonOnePressed = false
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            isButtonOnePressed = !isButtonOnePressed
            button2.setEnabled(!isButtonOnePressed)
            button3.setEnabled(!isButtonOnePressed)
        }

    });
```

You might also consider usind a ToggleButton, and then on every click -
just checking if one of the buttons is already pressed.

Comment: I need if the user clicks on one button the 2 buttons it can't be clicked.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, could you provide some images to demonstrate maybe?

Comment: if a user presses one button, then the other two buttons do not work but when he does to that button another click then you can select one of the buttons.

Comment: u can click on the link 
"enter image description here"

Comment: Well, as I said in my comment, I think you should try using ToggleButton (I'm just assuming you're using Button right now?), and then implementing onClickListener and check whether any of the other 2 buttons are in checked state using isChecked()

Comment: I don't need a toggle button, I need a button

Comment: Then, you could use the answer I edited earlier, is it not sufficient?

Comment: btw, you could use a custom togglebutton, which would look like a button, but would be easier to implement (imo)

Comment: I need to do it, in button, not a toggle button.

Answer (score 0):

```
  button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button2.setEnabled(false);
            button3.setEnabled(false);

            }

    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            button1.setEnabled(false);
            button3.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button1.setEnabled(false);
            button2.setEnabled(false);;
        }
    });

}
```